# EmbeddedId with MappedSuperclass: org.hibernate.MappingException: identifier mapping has wrong number of columns

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement a DB schema which involves `@MappedSuperclass` class having an `@EmbeddedId` id.

**Mappings** are as follows:

```java
// BaseUser - contains common fields for all kinds of users
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class BaseUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String type;

    String username;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

```java
// id class
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class CustomUserTypeId implements Serializable {

    @Column
    Long id;

    @Column
    String type;
}

// mapper super class with embedded id
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class CustomUserType {

    @EmbeddedId
    CustomUserTypeId customUserTypeId;

    @MapsId("id")
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "type", referencedColumnName = "type", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    @OneToOne
    public BaseUser baseUser;
}
```

```java
// actual entity using mapped super class
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class CustomerUserTypeA extends CustomUserType{
    String typeA_field1;
    String typeA_field2;
}
```

**Error:**

> Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: identifier mapping has wrong number of columns: com.example.jpahibernatetests.entities.CustomerUserTypeA type: component[id,type]

**Observations:**

Using JPA buddy, I checked the DDL for `CustomerUserTypeA`. It comes out as follows for PostgreSQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer_user_typea (
    typea_field1 VARCHAR(255),
    typea_field2 VARCHAR(255),
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_customerusertypea PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE customer_user_typea ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMERUSERTYPEA_ON_ID FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES base_user (id, type);
```

I think the CONSTRAINT should be defined as

```sql
ALTER TABLE customer_user_typea ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMERUSERTYPEA_ON_ID FOREIGN KEY (id, type) REFERENCES base_user (id, type);
```

but for some reason it is not.

---

What have I tried?

- Changing order of `@JoinColumns`
- Getting rid of `MappedSuperClass` and moving the logic to `CustomerUserTypeA`
- Using `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns` in place of `@JoinColumns`
- Verified types of `id` and `type` columns - both are `Long` and `String` respectively across all classes.

Deps:

- spring-boot: 3.2.3
- hibernate-core: 6.4.4.Final
- postgresql: 42.6.1